hono-sessions, Cookie-Store, working for multiple domains
I have a client React app that consumes data from multiple backends.
in development, those backends are

http://localhost:8001,
http://localhost:8002,
http://localhost:8003,
...
the authentication is handled from
http://localhost:8000
and my frontend app is running from
http://localhost:3000

In production, authentication is handled from

https://auth.mydomain.com
and the services are spread out through different subdomains of the same domain:
https://api.mydomain.com
https://statistics.mydomain.com
...
and my frontend app is running from
https://app.mydomain.com

Right now, i'm using Bearer Authentication, with a token generated in the auth server, decoded by the same middleware imported in every other service.
I would love to switch to cookie based session management, but I don't want to change the backend architecture setup, I also don't want to create an API Gateway if possible.
Is this possible with hono and hono-sessions?
How?
Thank you
